# JOIN в Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq2sql, asp.net-mvc, join, linq

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки. У меня возник вопрос по использованию `Linq2Sql`. Предположим, имеются таблицы следующего вида : 
[image]

Кроме этого у меня есть класс примерно такого вида:

```
public class SomeModel
{        
    public string DepartureCountryName { get; set; }       

    public string DepartureCityName { get; set; }       

    public string ArrivalCountryName { get; set; }

    public string ArrivalCityName { get; set; }
}
```

`SomeModel` - это модель, которая должна быть отображена на `View`. Она заполняется с помощью `Linq2Sql` запроса из таблицы `SomeTable`. Как мы видим в таблице `SomeTable` есть по два поля, ссылающихся на таблицы `Countries` и `Cities`. Для получения модели с помощью `LinqToSql` я делаю примерно следующее:

```
from some in dataContext.SomeTable
where какое_то_условие
select ConvertFromTableToModel(some)

//....... 

public SomeModel ConvertFromTableToModel(SomeTable some)
{
    return new SomeModel 
           {                                     
               DepartureCountryName =  dataContext.Countries.
                                       First(x => x.Id == some.DepartureCountryId),
               DepartureCityName    =  dataContext.Cities.
                                       First(x => x.Id == some.DepartureCityId),
               ArrivalCountryName   =  dataContext.Countries.
                                       First(x => x.Id == some.ArrivalCountryId),
               ArrivalCityName      =  dataContext.Cities.
                                       First(x => x.Id == some.ArrivalCityId),
           }
}
```

то есть получается, что для получения каждой `SomeModel` мне приходится в методе `ConvertFromTableToModel` делать по 4 запроса к базе для получения `DepartureCountryName`,
`DepartureCityName`,  `ArrivalCountryName` и `ArrivalCityName`. Всего таких `SomeModel` может быть 500-1000 штук на одной `view`. То есть требуется создать 2000-4000 запросов к базе, что сильно сказывается на производительности (страница рендерится примерно за 10-15 секунд). Можно ли как-то  улучшить эту ситуацию? Насколько мне известно здесь можно воспользоваться `join`-ом, но появляется необходимость делать `join` сразу по нескольким полям к одной таблице (DepartureCountryId и `ArrivalCountryId`, `DepartureCityId` и `ArrivalCityId`), поэтому никак не могу сообразить как этот `join` сделать. 
Перейти на `EntityFramework` или на `ADO.NET` к сожалению нельзя.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `LINQ to SQL` - это не только `LINQ`, но и `SQL` :)

можно оформить join в хранимую процедуру и добавить её к вашему DataContext

Comment: Извиняюсь, что говорю не по теме вопроса, но зачем вы сделали отдельную связь между SomeTable и таблицей стран? Здравый смысл подсказывает, что город может находиться всего в одной стране - а значит, при указании города отдельное указание страны не требуется.

Comment: @dthpth можно, но лучше не надо. Пока все работает достаточно быстро - лучше не выносить логику приложения в БД. потому что потом все это хозяйство очень тяжело обслуживать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не стоит ожидать ответа пояснений от топикастера если вопрос был задан два года назад :)

Answer (score 1):

**LinQ** создает поля с ленивой инициализацией, если есть связи в БД. Поэтому в вашем случае лучше написать вот так:

```
var result = dataContext.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.Id == id) //какое то условие писать тут
    .Select(x => new SomeModel
    {
        DepartureCountryName = x.Countrie.Name,
        DepartureCityName = x.Citie.Name,
        ArrivalCountryName = x.Countrie1.Name,
        ArrivalCityName = x.Citie1.Name,
    });
```

К сожалению, если вы создавали модель из Базы LinQ не подтягивает наименования связей. Из-за этого дублирующиеся связи между таблицами будут иметь такой вид `Countrie`, `Countrie1` и т.д. Вам придется заглянуть внутрь сгенерированного файла **dbml** чтобы понять по какому именно ключу эта связь.

Их можно или переопределить в автоматически сгенерированном файле **dbml**, но это не желательно, поскольку если вы потом обновите модель эту часть придется восстанавливать руками.

Другой вариант расширить ваши таблицы, сделав читаемыми названия связанных таблиц поскольку все сгенерированные классы имеют модификатор `partial`.

Результатом такой конструкции будет **SQL** инструкция уже содержащие все необходимые `JOIN` и вам нет нужды писать их вручную.

Мало того, она будет выполнена только в тот момент, когда результаты вычисления реально понадобятся в программе благодаря ленивым вычислениям внутри **LinQ**. Если вы хотите принудительно выгрузить из базы все в данном месте в конце выражения необходимо написать `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
var result = 
from s in dataContext.SomeTable
join c1 in dataContext.Countries on s.DepartureCountryId equals c1.Id
join ci1 in dataContext.Cities on s.DepartureCityId equals ci1.Id
join c2 in dataContext.Countries on s.ArrivalCountryId equals c2.Id
join ci2 in dataContext.Cities on s.ArrivalCityId equals ci2.Id
where какое_то_условие
select new SomeModel{
   DepartureCountryName = c1,
   DepartureCityName = ci1
   ArrivalCountryName = c2,
   ArrivalCityName = ci2
};
```

Comment: Не пишите явные джойны, когда есть связи в модели БД.  Линк умеет работать со связями.